# Pass images from one JS file to another through an Array and render in a component

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am having a lot of problems when I am trying to list all the tools I use to create websites using react. I decied to create a Data.js file to store all the data I needed. I don't think I need to used Redux or anything like that for this, but I could also be wrong about that

... I created a data.js file with an array:

```
import CSS from '../img/logo_css.png';
import HTML from '../img/logo_html.png';
import JS from '../img/logo_js.png';
import NODE from '../img/logo_node.png';
import REDUX from '../img/logo_redux.jpg';
import logoREACT from '../img/logo_react.png';
import STYLED from '../img/logo_SC.png';
import REACTrouter from '../img/logo_reactRouter.png';


export const tools = [
    {
        name: 'HTML 5',
        Description:
            'HTML5 is a markup language used for structuring and presenting content on the World Wide Web.',
        logo: { HTML },
    },
    {
        name: 'CSS 3',
        Description:
            'CSS is used for styling websites. CSS is a cornerstone technology alongside HTML and JavaScript',
        logo: { CSS },
    },
    { name: 'JavaScript', Description: 'JS desc', logo: { JS } },
    { name: 'React', Description: 'React desc', logo: { logoREACT } },
    {
        name: 'Node JS',
        Description: 'Node JS is Node JS MOTHER !!',
        logo: { NODE },
    },
    {
        name: 'Styled-Components',
        Description: 'Styled-Components is pimp !',
        logo: { STYLED },
    },
    { name: 'Redux', Description: 'Redux is SIIIIICK', logo: { REDUX } },
    {
        name: 'React Router',
        Description: 'React Router can go blow a goat',
        logo: { REACTrouter },
    },
];
```

in my component I import the data.js file and try to map over the array. The name, and description work fine... but the images are all broken links...

```
import React from 'react';
import { tools } from './Data';


class Boxes extends React.Component {
    renderTools() {
        console.log(`tools: ${tools}`);
        return tools.map((tool) => {
            return (
                <Box>
                    <BoxImg src={tool.logo} />
                    <h3>{tool.name}</h3>
                    <p>{tool.Description}</p>
                </Box>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BoxCon>
                <Container>
                    <BrandH1>The Tools That I Use To Craft Webpages</BrandH1>
                    {this.renderTools()}


                </Container>
            </BoxCon>
        );
    }
}

export default Boxes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are wrapping your image in brackets.

`logo: { HTML },` actually is `logo: { HTML: "link to image" }`.

change it to

`logo: HTML` and your code should work as is.